# How can I reliably get the timestamp of when a particular participant leaves(and joins) a room in twilio?

Tags: javascript, video, twilio, twilio-api

I am building a video chat app using twilio's programmatic video api. And would like to know how many minutes a particular participant is connected in a room.

I am currently listening to the roomJoined and room.on('disconnected') events to do ajax requests and update the timestamp on the server using a Date.Now(). 
But when the user closes the browser window in some cases, the request attached to the disconnected event wont fire as the javascript is removed from the dom before that code is executed.

Is there a reliable way to get this information?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Good news, you can now [create rooms using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource) and [setup to receive status callback webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#post-parameters) from those rooms. The [documentation for status callbacks are here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/status-callbacks), but the important callback you want is the `participant-disconnected`.

This particular event comes with a parameter that others do not. The `ParticipantDuration`, which is how long that participant was connected.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: When I try to create a room using the rest API, i am getting this error: Cannot read property 'rooms' of undefined.     
Here is th code:
        `client.video.rooms
            .create({
                uniqueName: req.params.id,
                statusCallback: 'localhost:3000/classrooms/listen'
            });`

Comment: What version of the Twilio node module are you using?